# How do I assign the "active" value to a tab on the first tab in a php while loop?

Tags: php, html, mysql, bootstrap-5

I'm using a while loop to populate tabs with PHP.  If I assign active while it's in the loop then they are all active.  This much I understand.  If I only want the first item / tab to have the class="tab-pane fade p-2 -->active<--" where should the script be changed?

```
while($row  = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
  $id = $row['id'];
  $in = $row['initial'];
  $name = $row['name'];     
echo "<div class=\"tab-pane fade p-2 active\" id=\"$in\" role=\"tabpanel\" aria-labelledby=\"$in-tab\">"; // make tabs
```

Answer (score 2):

Track an indicator that you've already rendered the "first" tab.  Something as simple as:

```
$firstTab = true;
```

Then within the loop, set it to `true` after rendering the "first" tab, conditionally including the `active` class:

```
$firstTab = true;
while($row  = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
  $id = $row['id'];
  $in = $row['initial'];
  $name = $row['name'];     
  echo "<div class=\"tab-pane fade p-2 " . ($firstTab ? "active" : "") . "\" id=\"$in\" role=\"tabpanel\" aria-labelledby=\"$in-tab\">";
  $firstTab = false;
}
```

Comment: That nailed it!  Thank you and I'm not sure I understand so if you have some reading I can do then please share it or explain what that just did.  Thank you again ... I wasn't sure how to even approach this.

Comment: @Anthony: There isn't really much to explain.  The goal is to know, for any given iteration of the loop, whether we're on the "first" iteration or not the "first" iteration.  There are likely a variety of ways to do that.  All this does is store that information in a variable.

Comment: Got it!  Specifically, this code kind of threw me "($firstTab ? "active" : "")".  I've seen and used it before but, I need to understand (and use it) it a little more.  Thank you for your help sir!

Answer (score 2):

First: write HTML as HTML, not using strings.

You'll need to use a index, like:

```
<?php
$i = 0;

while($row  = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
  $id = $row['id'];
  $in = $row['initial'];
  $name = $row['name'];
?>
<div class="tab-pane fade p-2 <?= $i === 0 ? 'active' : '' ?>" id="<?= $in ?>" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="<?= $in-tab ?>">
...
</div>
<?php
  $i++;
}
?>
```

Comment: I used the answer below and it worked.  I am sure this one would work too, can you explain the difference?

Comment: I agree with the HTML as HTML.  I started with one line having to comment out the quotes got carried away and just kept going :)  I am going to go back and fix this.  Very good advice for anyone reading this :)

Comment: Hi @Anthony. I wrote the answer at the same time as David. I didn't saw his answer until I click submit. His code work as well, but I think the Indexes could give you more opportunities to use it for other things (like show to the user the list order). His boolean only works for one specific thing: check if it's first or not.